# use applyInPandas with PySpark on a cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, pyarrow, pyspark-pandas

The `applyInPandas` method can be used to apply a function in parallel to a `GroupedData` pyspark object as in the minimal example below.

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# spark session object
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# test function
def func(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x

# run test function in parallel
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(8)})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf = sdf.groupby('x').applyInPandas(func, schema=sdf.schema)
dx = sdf.toPandas()
```

The minimal example has been tested on an 8 CPU single node system (eg a `m5.4xlarge` Amazon EC2 instance) and takes approximately 1 second to run, as the one-second sleep function is applied to each of 8 CPUs in parallel.  `pdf` and `dx` objects are in the screenshot below.

[image: pdf and dx objects]

**My issue is how to run the same minimal example on a cluster**, eg an Amazon EMR cluster.  So far, after setting up a cluster the code is being executed with a single core, so the code will require appx 8 sec to run (each function executed in series).

**UPDATE**

Following @Douglas M's answer, the below code parallelizes on an EMR cluster

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# test function
def func(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x

# run and time test function
sdf = spark.range(start=0, end=8, step=1, numPartitions=8)
sdf = sdf.groupby('id').applyInPandas(func, schema=sdf.schema)
now = datetime.now()
dx = sdf.toPandas()
print((datetime.now() - now).total_seconds()) # 1.09 sec
```

However using `repartition` does not parallelize (code below).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# test function
def func(x):
    sleep(1)
    return x

# run and time test function
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(8)})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf = sdf.groupby('x').applyInPandas(func, schema=sdf.schema)
sdf = sdf.repartition(8)
now = datetime.now()
dx = sdf.toPandas()
print((datetime.now() - now).total_seconds()) # 8.33 sec
```

Running the above code, the spark progressbar first indicates 8 tasks then switches to 1 task.
[image: spark progressbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark's parallelism is based on the number of partitions in the dataframe it is processing. Your `sdf` dataframe has only one partition, because it is very small.

It would be better to first create your range with the [`SparkSession.range`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.range):

> **`SparkSession.range`(*start: int, end: Optional[int] = None, step: int = 1, numPartitions: Optional[int] = None*) → pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame**
>
> Create a `DataFrame` with single `pyspark.sql.types.LongType` column named `id`, containing elements in a range from `start` to `end` (exclusive) with step value `step`.
>
> *New in version 2.0.0.*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **start : *int***
>   the start value
> - **end : *int, optional***
>   the end value (exclusive)
> - **step : *int, optional***
>   the incremental step (default: 1)
> - **numPartitions : *int, optional***
>   the number of partitions of the DataFrame
>
> **Returns: DataFrame**

For a quick fix, add repartition:

```py
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf).repartition(8)
```

Which will put each of the 8 elements into their own partition. The partitions can then be processed by separate worker cores.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  The solution based on ````SparkSession.range```` to parallelize the test function worked. The *quick fix* solution based on ````repartition```` did not work - see the update to the original question.  Any idea what is happening in that case?

Comment: @RussellBurdt Try to repartition before the action (e.g. right after creating the dataframe). Move your `.repartition(8)` by one line.